# Image of a natural transformation under an equivalence

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, functors

Let $C,D$ be a categories, $F,G:C\times C\to C$ functors with an natural isomorphism $\eta_X$ between them, and $E:C\to D$ an equivalence.

Is it true that $E(\eta_X)$ is a natural isomorphism as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given any morphism $f: (A,B) \to (A',B')$ in $C \times C$, then with your natural transformation $\eta_{(A,B)}: F(A,B) \to G(A,B)$ you have 
$$G(f) \circ \eta_{(A,B)} = \eta_{(A',B')} \circ F(f)$$
Applying $E$ on both sides, you get
$$EG(f) \circ E(\eta_{(A,B)}) = E(\eta_{(A',B')}) \circ EF(f)$$
so $\{E(\eta_{(A,B)})\}_{(A,B)}$ is a natural transformation between $EF$ and $EG$.

Note that $\eta$ is an isomorphism iff $\eta_{(A,B)}$ is an isomorphism for all objects $(A,B)$ in $C \times C$. Since functors map isomorphisms to isomorphisms we find that $E(\eta)$ is a natural isomorphism if $\eta$ is one. Note that we never used that $E$ is an equivalence, this works for arbitrary functors $C \to D$.

Comment: Thank you very much! So if I have a braiding $c$ for a category $C$, which is a natural transformation, then $E(c)$ is a braiding of $D$? At least it is again a natural transformation?

Comment: A braiding $c$ of $C$ is a natural transformation $c_{x,y} : x \otimes y \to y \otimes x$, so we get a natural transformation $E(c): E(x \otimes y) \to E(y \otimes x)$ but nothing more without further assumptions. To get a braiding you will have to have monoidal structures on $C$ and $D$ and $E$ to be a monoidal functor and an equivalence so that your braiding becomes $E(c_{E^{-1}(a),E^{-1}(b)}) : a \otimes b \cong E(E^{-1}(a) \otimes E^{-1}(b)) \to E(E^{-1}(b) \otimes E^{-1}(a)) \cong b \otimes a$.

Comment: Note that I am not completely rigorous here, since the isomorphisms left an right should also be included in the notation.

Answer (score 0):

Using juxtaposition for horizontal composition and $\cdot$ for vertical composition (and identifying functors with their corresponding identity natural transformations as appropriate)

Let $\eta : F \to G$ be any natural isomorphism and $E$ be *any functor at all*. Then by the interchange law,

$$(E \eta) \cdot (E \eta^{-1}) = (E \cdot E) (\eta \cdot  \eta^{-1}) = E G $$
$$(E \eta^{-1}) \cdot (E \eta) = (E \cdot E) (\eta^{-1} \cdot \eta) = E F $$

Both vertical composites are the respective identity natural transformations, and thus $E \eta^{-1}$ is the inverse of $E \eta$.

Answer (score 0):

I think as a matter of notation, it's worth asking what $E(\eta_X)$ really means—it's just a shorthand for the horizontal composition $\text{id}_{E}\circ \eta_X\in \text{Hom}_{D^{C\times C}}(E\circ F,E\circ G)$. And seeing as $\text{id}_{E}$, $\eta_X$ are both natural isomorphisms, their horizontal composition must also be a natural isomorphism (with explicit vertical inverse $\text{id}_E^{-1}\circ \eta_X^{-1}$).

Comment: I'm not sure this is really that helpful. Here "natural isomorphism" means isomorphism for the *vertical* composition, so the reason the composite is an iso has more to do with the functoriality of horizontal composition than it being a form of composition; and for this specific case it really boils down to the fact that $E$ is a functor, as the accepted answer already mentions.

Comment: Fair enough, it seems to boil down to applying interchange implicitly vs. explicitly.